# NgRx Effect - inner catchError executes multiple times

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I have an Angular app with NgRx, inside one of my effects I have a non expected behavior that, turns out, is expected, but I don't know how to fix it.

My minified code is

```
@Effect()
detelete$ = this.actions$
  .pipe(
    ofType<fromActions.DeleteRequested>(fromActions.ActionTypes.DeleteRequested),
    map(action => action.payload.id),
    mergeMap(id =>
      combineLatest([
        of(id),
        this.rservice.deleteById(id)
          .pipe(
            catchError((err, caught$) => {
              this.store.dispatch(new fromActions.DeleteCancelled({id: id}));
              return caught$;
            })
          )
      ])
    ),
    map(([id, ]: [string, any]) => {
      return new fromActions.DeleteSuccess({id: id});
    }),
  );
```

The reason I don't have my `catchError` on the same level as my `mergeMap` is that I need my `id` as payload for my `fromActions.DeleteCancelled` action. Plus, my service only returns a boolean, so I use `combineLatest` to persist it to my `onSuccess` `map`.

What I'm experiencing is this `catchError` is executing multiple times. Thus, dispatching my error action multiple times.
I foun that

> If you return this source, the observable will effectively restart all over again and retry

In this case the `source` is my `caught$`.

If, inside my `cacthError` I return

```
  return of(new fromActions.DeleteCancelled({id: id}));
```

It will still go to my `onSuccess map`. I could maybe check if my second param inside that `map` is os type `Action` or `boolean`, but I think there's a proper way to handle it and I don't know it.

[StackBlitz (uncomment `subscribe` to see infinite loop)](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-lks5sz?devtoolsheight=60)

Thanks.

Comment: Can you try `return [new fromActions.DeleteCancelled({id: id})];`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider this approach. Your code could looks like below:

```
import { EMPTY, of, Observable } from 'rxjs';
...

@Effect()
delete$ = this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType<fromActions.DeleteRequested>(fromActions.ActionTypes.DeleteRequested),
  map(action => action.payload.id),
  switchMap((id) => this.rservice.deleteById(id).pipe(
    switchMap(result => {
      return result ? of(new fromActions.DeleteSuccess({id: id})) : EMPTY
    }),
    catchError(error => {
      return of(new fromActions.DeleteCancelled({id: id}))
    })
  )
)
```

if your service is returning `true`, so `DeleteSuccess` action is dispatched, else an empty observable that completes immediately.
Because `EMPTY` returns an observable, you have to use `switchMap`, and also `of` to return an observable of action `DeleteSuccess`.

In case of error, `DeleteCancelled` is dispatched.

Another approach could be to use `@Effect({ dispatch: false })`, and manually dispatch all needed actions.

Hope it will help.

Comment: It worked like a charm. Marked as accepted, thank you.